# Problems with Android's UriMatcher 

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

In an answer to a previous question of mine someone indicated that there is some flakiness (for lack of a better word) inherent in the Android class UriMatcher. Can anyone pinpoint the known issues with UriMatcher? I'm designing a Content Provider that relies on UriMatcher to match my Uris correctly (as opposed to incorrectly I suppose). Are there workarounds to the known issues? Or is there a better strategy for matching Uris?

Example:

Here is the code setting my UriMatcher

```
private static final int MEMBER_COLLECTION_URI = 1;
private static final int MEMBER_SINGLE_URI = 2;
private static final int SUBMATERIAL_COLLECTION_URI = 3;
private static final int SUBMATERIAL_SINGLE_URI = 4;
private static final int JOBNAME_COLLECTION_URI = 5;
private static final int JOBNAME_SINGLE_URI = 6;
private static final int ALL_MEMBERS_URI = 7;
private static final int ALL_SUBMATERIAL_URI = 8;

static
{
        //return the job and fab for anything matching the provided jobName
        // JobNames/jobName
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "JobNames/*/",
                          JOBNAME_SINGLE_URI);
        //return a collection of members
        // jobName/member/attribute/value
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "*/member/*/*/",
                          MEMBER_COLLECTION_URI);
        //return a single member
        // jobName/member/memberNumber
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "*/member/*/",
                          MEMBER_SINGLE_URI);
        //return a collection of submaterial
        // jobName/submaterial/attribute/value
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "*/submaterial/*/*",
                          SUBMATERIAL_COLLECTION_URI);
        //return a single piece of submaterial
        // jobName/submaterial/GUID
        //GUID is the only way to uniquely identify a piece of submaterial    
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "*/submaterial/*",
                          SUBMATERIAL_SINGLE_URI);
        //Return everything in the member and submaterial tables
        //that has the provided attribute that matches the provided value
        // jobName/attribute/value
        //not currently used
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "JobNames/",
                          JOBNAME_COLLECTION_URI);
        //return all members in a job
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "*/members/",
                          ALL_MEMBERS_URI);

}
```

Add another Uri:

```
private static final int MEMBER_COLLECTION_URI = 1;
private static final int MEMBER_SINGLE_URI = 2;
private static final int SUBMATERIAL_COLLECTION_URI = 3;
private static final int SUBMATERIAL_SINGLE_URI = 4;
private static final int JOBNAME_COLLECTION_URI = 5;
private static final int JOBNAME_SINGLE_URI = 6;
private static final int ALL_MEMBERS_URI = 7;
private static final int ALL_SUBMATERIAL_URI = 8;
//ADDITIONAL URI
private static final int REVERSE_URI = 9;

static
{
        //return the job and fab for anything matching the provided jobName
        // JobNames/jobName
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "JobNames/*/",
                          JOBNAME_SINGLE_URI);
        //return a collection of members
        // jobName/member/attribute/value
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "*/member/*/*/",
                          MEMBER_COLLECTION_URI);
        //return a single member
        // jobName/member/memberNumber
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "*/member/*/",
                          MEMBER_SINGLE_URI);
        //return a collection of submaterial
        // jobName/submaterial/attribute/value
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "*/submaterial/*/*",
                          SUBMATERIAL_COLLECTION_URI);
        //return a single piece of submaterial
        // jobName/submaterial/GUID
        //GUID is the only way to uniquely identify a piece of submaterial    
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "*/submaterial/*",
                          SUBMATERIAL_SINGLE_URI);
        //Return everything in the member and submaterial tables
        //that has the provided attribute that matches the provided value
        // jobName/attribute/value
        //not currently used
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "JobNames/",
                          JOBNAME_COLLECTION_URI);
        //return all members in a job
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "*/members/",
                          ALL_MEMBERS_URI);
        //ADDITIONAL URI
        uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "*/reverse/*",
                          REVERSE_URI);

}
```

And the last Uri is not recognized using:
    uriMatcher.match(uri)

On the previous question (mentioned earlier) it was recommended that I move the offending Uri to the top of the calls to UriMatcher.put(String, int). That solved the previous problem (and left me with a bad taste in my mouth). Trying the same solution with this code results in the current first Uri (JOBNAME_SINGLE_URI) going unrecognized. I'm fairly sure that the issue isn't in my code (I've managed to create a working ContentProvider utilizing Uris and debug all of the problems with them prior to this issue), but rather is an issue with Uri matching in Android.

UPDATE:

```
public final static String AUTHORITY = "dsndata.sds2mobile.jobprovider";
```

Sample Uri:
    content://dsndata.sds2mobile.jobprovider/SDS2MobileDemo/reverse/C_1

Comment: I think you are adding extra slash (/) at the end of every path. Try removing that and see if it works.

Comment: That solution was offered on the previous question that I mentioned. It had no effect. Plus, I have other Uris with the trailing '/' that are recognized.

Comment: Also you should use # for the comparing the numbers or ids.

Comment: I'm not using numbers. Otherwise I would be.

Comment: What is your URI where JOBNAME_SINGLE_URI goes unrecognized?

Comment: If I move the REVERSE_URI to the top of the put statements then JOBNAME_SINGLE_URI goes unrecognized where it had previously worked.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are three rules that aren't well documented but that are crucial to understanding the matching mechanism of UriMatcher:

1. UriMatcher tries to match the entire Uri against the pattern. Much like the matches() method of java.util.regex.Matcher that returns true only if the entire region sequence matches the matcher's pattern (compared to the find() method that returns true for partial matches).
2. Wildcards are applied to one path segment only, meaning * or SDS2MobileDemo/* will never match SDS2MobileDemo/reverse/C_1 but */*/* or */*/C_1 will.
3. Once it finds a match for a path segment it won't find any alternative match for that particular path segment.

Here are some examples using the following url: content://dsndata.sds2mobile.jobprovider/SDS2MobileDemo/reverse/C_1

The first two rules are easy to understand:

- SDS2MobileDemo/*/* will match
- */reverse/* will match
- */* won't match because it matches only two path segments
- SDS2MobileDemo won't match because it matches only one path segment

The third rule is a little harder to understand.
If you add the following Uris in this exact order:

- */wrong/C_1
- SDS2MobileDemo/reverse/C_1

then it won't find a match because that translates into the following (pseudo) code:

```
if ("*".matches("SDS2MobileDemo")) {    
    // tries to match the other parts but fails    
}
else if ("SDS2MobileDemo".matches("SDS2MobileDemo")) {
    // will never be executed
}
```

If you reverse the order the (pseudo) code becomes:

```
if ("SDS2MobileDemo".matches("SDS2MobileDemo")) {    
    // tries to match the other parts and succeeds    
}    
else if ("*".matches("SDS2MobileDemo")) {    
    // will never be executed    
}
```

Now as far as the original question goes.
SDS2MobileDemo/reverse/C_1 will get matched by */reverse/* but not e.g. JobNames/reverse/C_1 because that one will go down the JobNames/* path...
Also it's clear that moving */reverse/* to the top isn't the solution because all other patterns not starting with * won't match any more.
There's really no telling what the correct solution is as long as it's unknown which patterns should match which Uris.

Answer (score 2):

Hum .... Ah typo ? Seems there is some whitespace after */reverse/*

```
uriMatcher.addURI(JobMetaData.AUTHORITY, "*/reverse/*", REVERSE_URI);
```

should work

EDIT

The example below works, try with your values and check your LogCat Window for warnings

Check the value in JobMetaData.AUTHORITY.

```
public static final String PROVIDER ="org.dummy.provider" ;

public static void doTest() 
{
  testUri("content://"+PROVIDER +"/test/reverse/xb32") ; 
  testUri("content://"+PROVIDER +"/JobNames/YES/") ;
}

private static void testUri(String pStr) 
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(pStr); 
    Log.w("Test", "uri = " + pStr) ;    
    int result = uriMatcher.match(uri) ;    
    Log.w("Test", "result = " + result) ;  
    List<String> list = uri.getPathSegments() ;   

    for (int i = 0  ; i < list.size() ; i++)
      Log.w("Test", "Segment" + i + " = " + uri.getPathSegments().get(i)) ;   
}
```

Comment: Whoops. That typo isn't in the original source. I must have accidentally added that when I was editing the question. It's fixed now.

Comment: Edited my answer, try to add this somewhere in you app and look in the console to find the warnings. Should be easy to pinpoint the problem.

Check also you ContentProvider class  => check if you forgot a case on one overriden function (query, delete, ...)

Comment: I've checked and rechecked to make sure that no cases were missing from the relevant overridden methods. Nothing is amiss there. Your example doesn't recreate the situation. Even if it does work, it doesn't necessarily mean that you've solved the problem.

Comment: what are your JobMetaData.AUTHORITY and could you provide a sample URI  string ?

Answer (score 1):

We can use Regex as a look around solution.

Here is the expression

```
https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?
```

It should work!

Comment: I'm using the "content" scheme for my Uris, not http. I'm not very good at regular expressions, but I don't think this would work for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a UriMatcher problem and solved it. Make sure that you always put wild cards exact matches. If you don', the UriMatcher code goes down the wildcard path and doesn't go back up if it chose the wrong path.

Unfortunately, I don't see exactly what's wrong in your case. I would try moving JOBNAME_COLLECTION_URI to the very top or removing it; I wonder if that's causing a problem.