# UriMatcher not recognizing pattern

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I'm having trouble with matching URIs in my `ContentProvider`. It will match paths with one or two "tags" (not sure what the correct term is), for example it can recognize `box/#`. But as soon as I add a second tag, for example `box/#/item`, I throw an `InvalidArgumentException` and my app crashes. I've read in several threads on here that this issue can sometimes be solved by changing the order of the URIs added to the `UriMatcher`; I tried this, but to no avail. Anyone know what the problem is? I've excerpted relevant parts of my code below.

From my `ContentProvider`:

```
private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.boxdatabase.DatabaseProvider";
// Type of query
public static final int BOXES = 100;
    ...

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY);
    ...

// URI Matcher for queries
private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static {
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "box/#/item", BOX_ITEM);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "box/#/item/#", BOX_ITEM_ID);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "box", BOXES);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "box/#", BOXES_ID);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "item", ITEMS);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "item/#", ITEMS_ID);
}
```

An example of where I try to access my `ContentProvider` and it fails:

```
return new CursorLoader(this, Uri.withAppendedPath(
                DatabaseProvider.CONTENT_URI, "box/" + boxId + "/item"),
                DatabaseContract.BoxItemEntry.ALL_COLUMNS, null, null, null);
```

Comment: can you show the stack trace and what line of code throws the exception

Comment: I throw the exception myself. I have a switch-case in the `query()` method with the results of `matchUri`; the default (URI match failed) is to throe an `InvalidArgumentException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "box", BOXES);
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "box/#", BOXES_ID);
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "box/#/item", BOX_ITEM);
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "box/#/item/#", BOX_ITEM_ID);
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "item", ITEMS);
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "item/#", ITEMS_ID);
```

The order is important, read my explanations here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15015687/534471

Comment: I figured out my problem, it was unrelated to the `UriMatcher`. However, this is very informative, so I'll go ahead and accept it as my answer. Hopefully others will find this useful!

Comment: Can `addURI(AUTHORITY, "item", ITEMS);` be placed after `addURI(AUTHORITY, "box", BOXES);` ?