# android getContentResolver().notifyChange() does not restart my loader

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-loadermanager, android-loader

codes:

First my Uris

```
public static final String PACKAGE    = "my.url.contentprovider";

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "NetworkTransaction";

public static final String AUTHORITY  = PACKAGE + ".NetTransContentProvider";

public static final Uri BASE_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+AUTHORITY);

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER  = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_URI,TABLE_NAME+"/*");

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_FIND_BY_ID  = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_URI,TABLE_NAME+"/FIND/ID");

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_INSERT_OR_REPLACE_BY_ID    = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_URI,TABLE_NAME+"/INSERT/REPLACE/ID"); 

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_INSERT_BY_ID   = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_URI,TABLE_NAME+"/INSERT/ID");
```

and my loader from activity code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(NET_TRANS_LOADER_ID,mBundle,this).forceLoad();

}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
    Uri uri = null;
    CursorLoader cl=null;
    switch (id) {
    case NET_TRANS_LOADER_ID:
        uri = NetTransContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_FIND_BY_ID;
        cl  = new CursorLoader(ChoosingUserNameActivity.this, uri, NetTransDbUtils.allColumns,
                NetTransDbUtils.COLUMN_ID + " = ? ",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(bundle.getLong(EXTRA_TRANSACTION_ID,-1))}, null);

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return cl;
}
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    final int loaderId = loader.getId();
    switch (loaderId) {
    case NET_TRANS_LOADER_ID:
        if(mTransactionId != null){
            NetTrans netTrans = NetTransDbUtils.cursorToNetTrans(cursor);
            if(netTrans != null && netTrans.getStatus() != null 
                                && !netTrans.getStatus().equals(NetTrans.STATUS_PENDING)){
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new NetTransMsg(true, mTransactionId, netTrans.getMessage()));
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

and at a runnable that runs on `ExecutorService` in a started service I call

`mContext.getContentResolver().insert(NetTransContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_INSERT_OR_REPLACE_BY_ID, cv );`

the value inserted but the loader dose not call:

```
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    int uriType = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (uriType) {

    case INSERT_OR_REPLACE_BY_ID:
        mDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        break;

    case INSERT_BY_ID:
        mDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER, null);
    return null;
}
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,String sortOrder) {
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME,projection,selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER);
        return cursor;
    }
```

my problem is `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER, null);` in the insert method can not make my loader restart.

---

**UPDATE**

**I have created a [sample project](https://github.com/hardworker93/ContentResolver_Bug), you press the button, a new `NetTrans` object is created and written into database, then the thread sleeps 5000 ms and overwrites that value (to simulate network operation). but after that loader dose not restart. Where is my bug ?**

Comment: You're creating the cursor loader using CONTENT_URI_FIND_BY_ID and then notifying on CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER. Since the cursor loader registers observers on the URI you pass in to query, it's not going to get notified (Unless CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER is the same as CONTENT_URI_FIND_BY_ID)

Comment: By doing that I will notify all `BASE_URI,TABLE_NAME+"/*"` look at the star.

Comment: Didn't notice that. Reading is fundamental. Stay in school, kids.

Comment: Check this out. I think the wildcard might not be matching properly http://stackoverflow.com/a/15015687/634474

Comment: @dymmeh if I use `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI_FIND_BY_ID, null);` still dose not work, the inser is called but the loader dose not restart :-(

Comment: @dymmeh can you have a look at this again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want observers registered on `CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER` to be notified when a change happens on `CONTENT_URI_FIND_BY_ID`, you need to make sure of two things.

- First, the `CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER` needs to be a parent of `CONTENT_URI_FIND_BY_ID`. If you think of it like folders on a file system, 'CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER' should contain `CONTENT_URI_FIND_BY_ID' in one of its sub folders.
- Second, you must pass true for the `notifyDescendants` argument when registering your content observer.

There is no wild card considerations when Android attempts to find matching content observers (the link provided in the comments only applies to the UriMatcher). So, to fix your problem you should remove the /* from your `CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER` and it should start matching. You can see how `my.url.contentprovider/NetworkTransaction`  is now a parent "folder" of `my.url.contentprovider/NetworkTransaction/INSERT/REPLACE/ID` where as before you had `my.url.contentprovider/NetworkTransaction/*`.

### EDIT 1

After reviewing your sample project, I have found the other area where your problem lies. When you use a cursor loader, the cursor is *owned* by the loader. This means that you shouldn't alter it in anyway aside from just iterating through its data. In your `NetTransDbUtils.cursorToNetTrans(cursor)` method, you are closing your cursor which will prevent the CursorLoader from being able to effectively monitor changes to your cursor's data.

Simple answer: Don't call close `cursor.close()` in `NetTransDbUtils.cursorToNetTrans(cursor);` for this use case.

Comment: Thank you, but still dose not work, I use `public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER   = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_URI,TABLE_NAME);` and `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER, null);`

Comment: Can you show the line where you are registering your loader to watch for changes?

Comment: dose not `cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER);`  do my job?

Comment: Ah I just noticed you were using a cursor loader so that should work. As far as I can tell everything should be working. Are you sure another query isn't coming in?

Comment: after each query I call  `setNotificationUri` so no matter what is happening it must work.

Comment: I meant are you sure the call to query() in your content provider isn't being called again? Have you added a log / set a break point in the debugger. Its possible your problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Uris with a simple parse:

```
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_ANY_OBSERVER = Uri
        .parse(BASE_URI + "/" + TABLE_NAME);
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_FIND_BY_ID = Uri
        .parse(BASE_URI + "/" + TABLE_NAME + "/FIND/ID");
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_INSERT_OR_REPLACE_BY_ID = Uri
        .parse(BASE_URI + "/" + TABLE_NAME + "/INSERT/REPLACE/ID");
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_INSERT_BY_ID = Uri
        .parse(BASE_URI + "/" + TABLE_NAME + "/INSERT/ID");
```

In your RestService class, use a handler for callbacks:

```
private Handler mHandler;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    mHandler = new Handler();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ...
    mHandler.post(task);
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you but first: I do not want to run my task on `UI thread` I want to use multiple threads(`ExecutorService`), second `Uri.withAppendedPath` dose the same.

Comment: @mmlooloo I'd say that `Uri.withAppendedPath` does the same, but without it, it doesn't work. You may want to update your question, because with these changes it works, so your problem is in using the ExecutorService.

Comment: If I use your answer I will get `NetworkOnMainThread` exception and also I do not like to use `IntentService` because it just dose one job at a time, can you tell me why the `NetTrans`  inserted but it dose not restart my loader ? this is all my question: **getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange** dose not work.

Comment: @mmlooloo you can just call the handler once all the network work is done.  onStartCommand runs on another thread.

Comment: No  `onStartCommand` runs on `UI thread` please read the doc.

Comment: @mmlooloo ahh you're absolutely right. I don't see why you can't create another thread for your work and then notifyChange on the UI thread via the handler though.

Comment: Yes I can and instead of using handler I  use `EventBus`, but I just want to know why I have to do this and also is it my bug or android or anything else ...